# Лишние знаки при вставке из буфера в VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Иногда когда копирую что то на стороне и вставляю в VS, появляются лишние пробелы - которых не было, решается одним нажатием Ctrl+Z.

Почему так происходит ?
Как то можно эту медвежью услугу отключить ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123519/discussion-on-question-by-vipz--------vs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идём в настройки Студии и снимаем чекбокс:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > General > Automatically format on paste

Comment: Большое спасибо!